# How to get endpoint of AWS API gateway created through SAM using javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I am creating an api gateway from a SAM template.  I need a separate web page to make get requests to the api using javascript.  However, I am unsure how to make requests if I don't know the endpoint since the endpoint is created dynamically on deployment.

Is there a way to somehow send the endpoint to the webpage or for the webpage to access the endpoint without knowing it.

I understand that I could name the API using the SAM template but I want everything to be created by AWS so that there are no conflicts with multiple deployments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of a few things here.

1. Would your webpage be able to make an authenticated call to AWS? You could export your API endpoint in the stack outputs section and be able to pick that up via the API.
2. Do you expect your API endpoint to change often? Once an API is created in a stack, the endpoint never changes unless that API is deleted. You could create your API then use the endpoint url in your webpage.
3. You could use Route53 to map your API endpoint to a normal web address, so that the address would always be the same. You could put that address in your webpage and not need to have the exact API endpoint url.